# How to disable socket send buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client, buffer

I have a C++ tcp socket client application which sends data to server.

Because of buffer, `send()` function returns a byte size, like send is success.

So, when internet connection is not stable, I cannot get the info if data is sent or waiting in the buffer.

I need a method which lets me instanly get if connection is live or dead. So I don't call send function.

- Can it be done with disabling the buffer? (Hoping `send()` returns error if connection is dead)
- Or do you suggest a ping or checking network with some other way before `send()`?

***(Server is not returning a message and doesn't support keep-alive connection)***

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: There's no way to know if a message that fits in the buffer will actually be successfully transmitted or not by only using `send`. Depending on the data you send and how often you send it, you could save the data and discard it after the *next* `send` call returns with success (and then save that newly sent data, and so on). Or modify the protocol so it contains some kind of request-response sequence, or at least an acknowledge that a message has been received (and not send anything else unless the ack has been received).

Comment: It still wouldn't solve you problem because even if the data was sent, you wouldn't know whether the server got the data. Apparently you can use `getsockopt` with `TCP_INFO` to see how much data the other side hasn't acked, though!

Comment: TCP is designed to persist outages, so it takes time for the OS to detect a lost connection. The only way to make your code detect a dead connection sooner rather than later is to use timeouts in your own code. Preferably by designing this into your communication protocol. If you haven't received data from the peer for awhile, try to send something to the peer. If the peer doesn't ack it, close the connection.  If this design is not possible for your code, then you can at least enable TCP keep-alives on the socket itself, and let the OS handle this ping/pong logic internally for you.